# Import data from CouchDB to Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, couchdb, migrate

Is there a way to export data from couchDB to Sql Server ? 
We tried with SSiS using http connection manager, JSON component source etc. But the problem is that couchDB has some security and we can't retrieve data info. We tried installing their certificates no success.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: It wont help you now, but couchdb 4.0 is going to have a SQL like interface that you might be able to use via the odbc connector. Would be worth knowing about for the future!

Answer (score 1):

CounchDB has a number of .net client libraries you can use. I would get that working in a console app and then just write that to a csv on the disk and use SSIS to import it.

If you don't want the additional step you could write a .net script source component that used the .net client to retrieve data *but* get it working in a console app first so you know it is good before bringing SSIS into the equation.

Getting started with CouchDb and c#:

https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_C%23

ed